# Input datetime when double click on a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 6 columns in google sheet doc. 
(A) Date    (B)Order (C)ID  DEPARTMENT  (D)**Time sent**    (E)**Time received**    (F)Delivery time

I want each time I double click column a cell under **Time Sent** or **Time received** columns - current date and time is inputted.

Date and time should stay forever (like the time of double click).

Can you please help me to create this code?

Comment: google sheets is not excel and vba is not google apps scirpt. I updated the tags so it is clear to you and to other readers what your purpose is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

There is no `doubleClick` event in Google Apps Script.

- However, you can use [onSelectionChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) to capture **single** click events.
- The following script will set the value of a cell in column D or E with the current datetime upon a single click.
- To prevent a cell from being updated after you selected again, you can add an extra condition to set values only when the selected cell is empty. If the cell has already a date in it, then don't update it. In this way, the original/first datetime will remain intact.

### Solution:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  if (as.getName() == 'Sheet1' && row>1 && [4,5].includes(col) && e.range.getValue()==''){ 
        e.range.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

To use this solution, simply copy & paste it to the script editor and save the changes. After that, it will automatically be used upon single click events. In this solution I used `Sheet1` as the sheet name. Feel free to change that according to your specific case.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined (line 2, file "Code")

Comment: @GlebKozlovskiy this function is **not** supposed to be ran/executed manually. It is not a regular function but a trigger function which is executed only on selection changes as the name indicates. Therefore, don't run it manually by the script editor because that's not how you use it.